# Adicionar checkbox dinâmico gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Estou adicionando os campos do gridview via código, porém o checkbox não aparece, em vez de aparecer a caixa de seleção, aparece: `"System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox"`

Segue como estou fazendo:

```
CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
if (Session["dt1"] != null)
{
    dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dt1"];
}
else
{
    dt1.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Nome");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Quantidade");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Valor");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Desconto");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Valor Final");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Quitar");
}
dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
dr1["ID"] = txtidprodutoAdd.Text;
dr1["Nome"] = cbProdutoAdd.SelectedItem;
dr1["Quantidade"] = UpQuantidade.Text;
dr1["Valor"] = txtValorAdd.Text;
dr1["Desconto"] = txtDescontoAdd.Text;
dr1["Valor Final"] = txtValorFinalAdd.Text;
dr1["Quitar"] = check;

dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);
GridView5.DataSource = dt1;
GridView5.DataBind();
Session["dt1"] = dt1;
```

Este código funciona normal quando eu adicionava o type bool e vinha marcado, porém agora preciso que o usuário tenha o controle de marcar e desmarcar qualquer linha do gridview.

Comment: Você quer adicionar o Checkbox dentro do Grid certo? Se for isso você precisa adicionar uma coluna template, você nao pode colocar ele dentro do datatable dessa forma.

Comment: Mas preciso criar o checkbox na hora que adiciona os dados, e preciso adicioná-lo dessa forma.

Comment: sim, mas dessa forma que você está fazendo não funciona. Colocar um objeto dentro do datareader, você tem que adicionar dinamicamente a coluna ItemTemplate com o Checkbox no seu Gridview.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/366948/How-to-add-checkbox-in-gridview-dynamically  dá uma olhada aqui se é isso que você precisa.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13462/How-to-create-template-columns-dynamically-in-a-gr

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro eu sei criar ele com itemtemplate, só que como posso fazer então pra que ele seja a última coluna do Grid? porque assim ele fica sendo a primeira.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque ele está fazendo um `ToString()` no `check` (Checkbox) que você está adicionando.

Esse `ToString()` está sendo feito provavelmente pelo tipo de dados da coluna `"Quitar"` da sua `DataTable`.

Segundo [essa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630933/how-to-add-a-checkbox-control-to-a-datatable) você precisa mesmo adicionar a coluna com o tipo `bool`.

Assim, na criação da coluna ficaria desse jeito:

```
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quitar", typeof(bool)));
```

E o usuário deve sim estar apto a marcar ou desmarcar a caixa de seleção.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu já tinha feito desta forma Diego, porém ele não deixa o usuário marcar, o campo vem como se fosse desabilitado.

Comment: O DataTable não determina se o componente renderizado vai ficar habilitado ou não. [Isso é no GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx). [Veja se não está definindo o `ReadOnly` como true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550217/unable-to-change-checkbox-status-in-datagridview-c-sharp-winforms) (acho que vi em algum lugar que esse é o valor definido quando se faz o `DataBind`).

Answer (score -3):

it is necessary that you create an option to enable, because by default it comes configurator as disabled, You can do this as below.
in creating the column it would look like this:

```
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quitar", typeof(bool)));

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fnSelectAll() {
        const disabledAllCheckboxInPage = 
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']"))
        disabledAllCheckboxInPage.forEach(item => item.disabled = false)
    }
</script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
               <input id="chkAll" type="checkbox" onclick="fnSelectAll()" />
             </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```